# update to next value in the column mysql after 15 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create an event in PHP and MySQL that updates the value in agent_id column of leads table every 15 minutes. The agent_id value comes from the agent_id column of assignments table depending on various conditions in the WHERE clause. I want to create a loop or a LIFO stack where the agent_id is updated to next value in agent id column of assignments table. The assignments table looks like:

```
agent_id    broker_id
556             603
256             603
301             603
336             600
225             600
```

The SQL query to update the agent_id field is

```
UPDATE leads
JOIN assignments ON leads.queue_id=assignments.queue_id
JOIN regions ON assignments.user_id=regions.user_id
JOIN subscriptions ON assignments.user_id=subscriptions.user_id
SET leads.agent_id=assignments.user_id
WHERE leads.queue_id='1' AND leads.category_id=subscriptions.category_id AND 
leads.county=regions.county
```

How do I update to next value for eg: if 556 is the first value then after 15 minutes the value is updated to next value in column i.e. 256 and broker_id 603. 
And when it reaches the last value 301, then after 15 minutes, the column should be updated to 556 again. I'm new to coding in general, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Gurvinder Singh

Comment: This sounds like a very poor design.

Comment: I guess you could just store a timestamp against each row, and forget about the trigger

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff

Comment: There's no such thing as an implicit *next value* in SQL.  Rows of tables have no order unless you give them one in a query with `ORDER BY`.  If you query the table twice in a row and the rows come out in the same order both times, you should treat that as an accident of fate. So your problem, the way you've specified your assignments table, cannot reliably be solved.

Comment: @O.Jones What if I order it by created_at time and date?

Comment: Sure, if you have some way to order the rows, good.